# How to print a non-asci (¥) character in assembly

Tags: assembly, unicode, x86, gnu-assembler

To print a letter in assembly I can do something like:

```
y:  .ascii "y"
mov $SYS_STDOUT,    %edi
lea y,              %rsi
mov $1,             %edx
mov $SYS_WRITE,     %eax
syscall
```

How can I do this for a non-asci character, such as printing the letter/symbol `¥` ?

Comment: Put the unicode bytes into the buffer, and print the correct amount. Looks like `.byte 0xc2, 0xa5` for utf-8.

Comment: @Jester oh, thanks that is easier than I thought! Where did you look up the utf-8 charactres? This one looks ok: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C2%A5&mode=char.

Comment: google search shows it directly. But you can use any of various web sites too such as [fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a5/index.htm). Locally if you can produce it somehow you can use a hexdump tool.

Comment: @Jester ok thanks. `xxd` is good when I have the symbol

Comment: Yeah, pasting into `hexdump -C` in a terminal is what I usually do for local hexdump.

Comment: It depends on the API you use. "print" is not a things for assembly. Either you put into video memory, or you tell BIOS to print it, or you send to terminal (and so using OS and/or above layers). You are using POSIX [it seems], but 1 (stdout) could be linked to many different things, maybe not aware of non ASCII characters